# Как сделать перебор и вывод всех возможных комбинаций из заданных символов?

Tags: алгоритм, delphi, комбинаторика

*Пишу на Delphi. Нужна небольшая помощь с алгоритмом, или примером кода.*

Есть набор символов (для примера 5 шт, но на самом деле будет больше сотни),
a,b,с,d,e. Нужно составить список всех возможных комбинаций из этих символов. Например:

1. a
2. b
3. c
4. d
5. e
6. ab
7. ac
8. ad
9. ...
10. abcde
11. ....

Но с условием, что каждый символ должен повторяться в комбинации, только один раз. И наборы символов "ab" и "ba" считать разными комбинациями.

-----ДОПОЛНЕНО-----

```
procedure Generate(list, comb: TStringList; idx: integer);
var
  temp :  TStringList;
  i, k : integer;
begin
  temp              := TStringList.Create;
  temp.Duplicates   := dupIgnore;
  temp.Sorted       := false;


  if idx >  list.Count-1 then begin
    if  comb.Count-1 > 0 then
      Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(comb.Text);
    Exit;
  end;

  for k := 0 to comb.Count-1 do begin
    temp.Assign(comb);      // заменил строку присвоения на Assign
    temp.Insert(k, list[idx]);
    Generate(list, temp, idx + 1);
  end;
  Generate(list, comb, idx + 1);

comb.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Во-первых, где свои наработки?  Во-вторых, для `больше сотни` вывод не получится, т.к. количество будет непомерное - например, для 20 символов - 6613313319248080000 вариантов.

Comment: @MBo , большое спасибо за ответ! Изначально я поделил задачу на 2 части. 1) Поиск всех возможных вариантов 2) их фильтрация (т.к нужны будут не все) Но после Ваших слов, думаю будет правильнее фильтровать их на этапе создания комбинаций, и оставлять только нужные. Простой пример как я себе это представляю, я дополнил куском кода в своем вопросе. Но код не перебирает все варианты. Что бы решить эту задачу, надо больше вложенных циклов, я так понимаю?

Comment: Код я добавил. Но если нужны не все, лучше, конечно, генерировать только нужные.

Comment: @MBo, Огромное спасибо! похоже, это именно то, что мне нужно!

Comment: @MBo, простите что надоедаю, но мне без Вас никак. Вас не затруднит переделать этот код, для работы со списком? Как оказалось, в моей задаче создание комбинаций будет идти не только по символам, но и по фразам.

Comment: Вместо вставки символа вставлять элемент списка. Однако копирование-сохранение изрядно времени займёт.

Comment: @MBo, я заменил, но видимо что то не правильно( Вы не могли бы посмотреть?

Comment: Да. Нужно понимать, что происходит здесь:`temp := comb;` и чем это отличается от строк.

Comment: Там список строк, и в данной строке мы список с комбинацией, присваиваем временному списку. Или нужно построчно это сделать?

Comment: Нужно глубокое копирование, иначе две переменные указывают на один и тот же объект (+ утечка). Assign

Comment: @MBo,  эм...заменил строку присвоения на `temp.Assign(comb);` но проблема осталась. Показывает ошибку "Invalid pointer operation" (

Comment: Сделайте новый вопрос, как будет возможность - попробую ответить, или кто-нибудь ещё ответ даст.

Comment: @MBo, хорошо. Огромное спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Число таких комбинаций растёт экспоненциально, поэтому для больших наборов получить всё нереально.

Для генерации комбинаций из наборов разумного размера существует немало возможностей.

Например, можно генерировать комбинации рекурсивно. На K-ом уровне рекурсии используется один K-й символ. Он вставляется во все возможные места имеющихся комбинаций, а также используется вариант без этого символа. Например, на 3 уровень приходят комбинации '', 'a', 'b', 'ab', 'ba'. Для последней из них на следующий уровень передаются 'ba' ('c' не используется), 'cba', 'bca', 'bac'

```
procedure Generate(s, comb: string; idx: Integer);
var
  i, k: Integer;
  temp: string;
begin
  if idx > Length(s) then begin
    if Length(comb) > 0 then
      Writeln(comb);
    Exit;
  end;

  for k := 1 to Length(comb) + 1 do begin
    temp := comb;
    Insert(s[idx], temp, k);
    Generate(s, temp, idx + 1);
  end;
  Generate(s, comb, idx + 1);
end;

begin
  Generate('abc', '', 1);
  Readln;
end.
```

Можно также перечислить все ненулевые подмножества входного набора - их будет `2^n-1`, и для каждого (размером k) сгенерировать все k! перестановок

Answer (score 0):

Вариант "в лоб". Берётся строка длиной k, где k - количество используемых символов.

1. В k-ю позицию ставится 1-й символ, затем 2-й и т.д.
2. Когда символы закончатся, в (k-1)-ю позицию ставится 1-й символ, потом повторяется п.1, только теперь пропускаются "ведущие" символы.
3. Действия повторяются по аналогии пока вариантов не останется.

Пример.
символы abc

```
1. '__a'
2. '__b'
3. '__c'
4. '_ab'
5. '_ac'
6. 'abc'
7. 'bac'
8. 'cab'
9. 'cba'
```